# Is it legal in C++11 to inherit from private nested type?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, pimpl-idiom

What I am trying to do is to have a variable-size POD as a Pimpl in my library class:

```
// header file
class foo {
public:
    // ctors, copy, move, dtor, etc.

private:
    struct impl; // forward-declared
    impl* pimpl; // pointer to private implementation
};
```

Then define several fixed-size implementations like this:

```
// .cpp implementation file
struct foo::impl {
    uint32_t refs;
    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t len;
    uint32_t data;
};

static_assert( sizeof( typename foo::impl ) == 16, "paranoia" );

namespace { // anonymous
    typedef typename foo::impl base;

    template <size_t S>
    struct block : base {
        static_assert( S > 16, "invalid block size" );
        static_assert((( S - 1 ) & S ) == 0, "block size must be power of 2" );

        uint8_t pad[S - 16];
    };

    typedef block<64>  block64;
    typedef block<128> block128;
    // ...
}

// foo implementation using the above PODs
```

GCC versions 4.6 and 4.7 have no issues compiling this with `-std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic`, but I am still fuzzy about legality of using private nested type name like that. Wading through my [maybe outdated draft] copy of C++11 standard did not give me any better clues.

If anybody can point me to anything (preferably a section in the standard) that proves this one way or the other (legal or not) I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: This doesn't look legit to me. `impl` is private, why anyone can access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation you have is not legal: Access to `foo::impl` is private, i.e., only the definition of `foo` or its members can reference it. In the implementation file you reference the name at namespace scope.

The relevant part of the standard is 11 [class.access] paragraph 1 and paragraph 4.

Comment: Thanks, Dietmar. Does the first note in 11 paragraph 4 mean that if I include public `typedef impl bar;` in class `foo` declaration, it would be legal to use name `foo::bar` instead of `foo::impl` outside of the class scope? Is there any difference here from just making forward declaration of `impl` public?

Comment: I think that providing an accessible `typedef` provides the accessible name needed. It wouldn't be any different than making the local struct publically accessible.

Answer (score 4):

I think that this isn't allowed. Although there's a note in the standard that

> Because access control applies to names, if access control is applied to a typedef name, only the accessibility of the typedef name itself is considered. The accessibility of the entity referred to by the typedef is not considered.

So in

```
struct block : base
```

the name `base` is accessible. However the typedef itself uses the name `foo::impl`, which is private and therefore inaccessible. The name also would be inaccessible in the static_assert.

I don't see any exceptions that would allow the name to be accessed in these contexts.

My compiler produces these errors for this code:

```
main.cpp:16:27: error: 'impl' is a private member of 'foo'
static_assert(sizeof(foo::impl) == 16, "paranoia");
                          ^
main.cpp:4:12: note: declared private here
    struct impl; // forward-declared
           ^
main.cpp:19:27: error: 'impl' is a private member of 'foo'
    typedef typename foo::impl base;
                          ^
main.cpp:4:12: note: declared private here
    struct impl; // forward-declared
           ^
```

---

One option might be to include a public friend in `foo`, which will have access to the private names inside `foo`. Then you can place the definition of that friend type in the cpp file so that the names it exposes are exposed only in that one file:

```
// header
struct foo {
    struct private_public_access;
private:
    struct impl;
};

// cpp
struct foo::impl {};

struct private_public_access {
    typedef foo::impl foo_impl;
};

typedef private_public_access::foo_impl base;
```

Anyone will be able to use the name `private_public_access`, but they won't have the definition and so won't be able to access `private_public_access::foo_impl` (although they could define it themselves to gain access...). Although if this is acceptable then maybe it'd be just as acceptable to leave the name `foo::impl` public and its definition hidden like it already is (and like `private_public_access`'s definition is hidden).

Comment: Thanks. What compiler/version are you using?